# Java: Pass arguments to constructor from List

Tags: java, junit

I have class T which is extended by classes A, B, C. Each class has different fields. I need to test each subclass by creating it and running some methods however I'd rather use `@Theory` and `@Datapoints` than a separate test for each. Can I do that?

I thought about:

```
@Datapoints
List<Pair>
```

where Pair would be linking:

- `Class<? extends T>` for which subclass, with
- `List<?>` for the arguments needed for the constructor

But I am stuck now on how to create the objects from the given class with the given arguments inside `@Theory`. Can it be done? Any suggestions?

Edit: seems like the above is not clear. Here is an example:

```
class Pair<L, R> {
    private L l;
    private R r;
    ...
} 

class T {
    private String field1;

    T(String s) {
        this.field1 = s;
    }  
} 

class A extends T {
    private String field2;

    A(String s1, String s2) {
        super(s1);
        this.field2 = s2;
    } 
}

class B extends T {
    private String field3;
    private String field4;

    A(String s1, String s2, String s3) {
        super(s1);
        this.field3 = s2;
        this.field4 = s3;
    }  
}

@RunWith(Theories.class)
class Test {
    @Datapoints
    public static List<Pair> = Arrays.asList{
        new Pair(A.class, Arrays.asList(field1, field2)), 
        new Pair(B.class, Arrays.asList(field1, field3, field4)) 
    };

    @Theory
    public void test(Pair p) {
        ?? 
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it can. I would be curious to see more of your setup though, to be able to provide a response to your case

Comment: Please: don't explain what your code is doing. Instead put up a [mcve]. Why confuse readers with explanations - so that 10 readers have 10 different assumptions on how your code looks in detail?!

Comment: have added an example. Hope it is sufficient

Comment: Do you know anything about reflection?

Comment: @RealSkeptic not really

Comment: Well, reflection is the only way to produce an instance from a class dynamically. Here's a [link to the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the gist of what worked for me:

```
class T {
    private String field1;

    T(String s) {
        this.field1 = s;
    }  
} 

class A extends T {
    private String field2;

    A(String s1, String s2) {
        super(s1);
        this.field2 = s2;
    } 
}

class B extends T {
    private String field3;
    private String field4;

    A(String s1, String s2, String s3) {
        super(s1);
        this.field3 = s2;
        this.field4 = s3;
    }  
}

@RunWith(Theories.class)
class Test {
    // this can probably be array of arrays instead
    @Datapoints
    public static List<List> = Arrays.asList{
        Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(A.class), 
                      Arrays.asList(String.class, String.class),  
                      Arrays.asList(field1, field2)), 
        Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(B.class), 
                      Arrays.asList(String.class, String.class, String.class),
                      Arrays.asList(field1, field3, field4)) 
    };

    @Theory
    public void test(List l) {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(l.get(0).get(0).toString());
        Class[] types = (Class[]) l.get(1).toArray();
        Object[] args = l.get(2).toArray();


        T t = (T) c.getConstructor(types).newInstance(args);

        //do whatever with t
    }
}
```